# mktime() giving different results for same input in different timezone

Tags: c, datetime, timezone, mktime

Here is the piece of code for converting `Fri Jan  1 00:00:00 IST 1970` to EPOCH

```
 memset(&Date_st,0,sizeof(struct tm));
 Date_st.tm_year = 70;
 Date_st.tm_mon  = 0;
 Date_st.tm_mday  = 1;
 Date_st.tm_hour = 24;
 Date_st.tm_min  = 0;
 Date_st.tm_sec  = 0;
 Date_st.tm_isdst = 0 ; 
 date_in_seconds = mktime( &Date_st );
```

The code is running on two servers having different time zones

> **Server_1!:user_1**> Tue Aug 25 11:03:51 **IDT** 2015
>
> **Server_2!:user_2**> Tue Aug 25 05:05:03 **CLT** 2015

Now the code gives different output on different servers for same input which is `Fri Jan  1 00:00:00 IST 1970`

```
Server_1 -> 79200
Server_2 -> 100800
```

**Can someone suggest why output is different? and how can it be make same** {I want it to be same} ?

Comment: For `Jan  1 00:00:00 1970`, use `Date_st.tm_hour = 0;` not 24.

Answer (score 1):

That's what timezones are all about, the local time is different.

You might want to try the `gmtime` function instead, if you want a common reference for the time.

Comment: is there any possibility of this behavior due to some env. var. ?
I am asking this because things was working on the same env {machine}